# Allow users to sign into exchange email with their own account | One email address multiple users

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

we have a "secure" mailbox which is set up in a specific manner, which is used by multiple users. As with other mailboxes, we just added it as a shared mailbox to the users Outlook. The problem is that emails sent from that mailbox land in the user's mailbox `sent` directory, which is against our policy. The sent email should be in the "secure" mailboxes `sent` folder and shouldn't touch the user's at all.

Our second approach was to just add the "secure" mailbox as a second mailbox to the user's outlook profile (not as shared mailbox). The problem here is that every user needs to know the password of the "secure" mailbox, which isn't really desirable.

**Is there a way to configure the mailbox or make changes to the exchange set up to allow the users to sign into the "secure" mailbox with their own account?**

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to save the sent items to the shared mailbox by default.

Method 1: Set the DelegateSentItemsStyle registry value on the Outlook client

Method 2: Configure the mailbox to save a copy of the message to the Sent Items folder of the shared mailbox in Exchange Online or in on-premises Exchange Server

See [Messages sent from a shared mailbox aren't saved to the Sent Items folder of the shared mailbox in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2843677/messages-sent-from-a-shared-mailbox-aren-t-saved-to-the-sent-items-fol) for more details.